Merge sort algorithm parallelization speed-up
I am doing a theoretical exercise for a class about a theoretical study of parallelizing the mergesort algorithm and the speed-up obtained for different amounts of cores.
I am using the following approach:
Using the merge sort tree, each level must be executed after the previous one, so they are sequential. However, tasks (divide or merge) of the same level are independent so they can be executed concurrently. This would make the maximum number of cores for which we can obtain some speed-up compared to the sequential version n/2 (n is the size of the input list).
However, the proposed solution states the following:
We when forming the lists, we spawn a thread for the computation of left in the MergeSort code, and spawn a thread for the computation of the right. If we consider this recursively, for n initial elements in the array, we can utilize 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + .... + log2(n) processors to obtain speedup.In this question, log2(n) is the largest value of Y for which we can obtain any speedup without restructuring.
Y being the number of cores.
I don't understand why it log2(n) is the maximum number of cores to obtain speed-up and not n/2. Could someone explain it to me?

"for n initial elements in the array, we can utilize 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + .... + 2 ^ log2(n)? The number of levels in the tree is log2(n).

In the book the 2^ is not there, which is weird. I also think your correction makes more sense. But it doesn't seem like an error in the book as it repeats the same log2(n) in "In this question, log2(n) is the largest value of Y for which we can obtain any speedup without restructuring."

What book is this? Does the book not have more explanation than the brief paragraph you ... paraphrased(?). I take it that "Y" in that paragraph is the number of cores?

The book is "Computer Organization And Design: Hardware/Software Interface" it is exercise 6.5. It has no more explaination in the solution of the exercise. The only other piece of information is the exercise itself. Yes, Y is the number of cores.

An issue is the needless spawning of threads for left. The code starts of with a single thread, spawns 2 threads for left and right for a total of 3 threads, then spawns 4 threads for a total of 7 threads, ... .
Instead the code should use the existing thread for left, and only spawn threads for right, then the total number of threads for each level will be powers of 2: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ..., and not 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, ... .
The exercise states that the limit is 1+2+4+...+log2(n), not just log2(n), but that is still wrong. For 256 elements, the limit would be 1+3+7+15+31+63+127 = 247 cores | processors.
A bottom up approach would be much simpler. Divide the array into Y parts, sort each of the Y parts using Y cores, then use Y/2 cores to merge Y parts into Y/2 parts, Y/4 cores to merge Y/2 parts into Y/4 parts, ... , 1 thread to merge 2 parts into 1 part (the sorted result).
The amount of speed up depends on cache and memory access versus register operations. Register operations can run in parallel, but most systems have a single memory bus, and memory operations can't be run in parallel. Each core can load blocks of memory into cache in fast sequential order (versus slower random access reads), and can write from cache in fast sequential order, but at some number of threads, sorting becomes memory bound and not CPU bound, in which case no further speedup can be achieved.

Top down | recursive merge sort is mostly academic. Actual libraries use some hybrid variation of insertion sort + bottom up | iterative merge sort, such as tim sort.

Thanks for the response. So, the number of cores after which the increase in the speed-up plateaus would be length(list)/2 no?

@tiredStudent - probably much less than that. My guess is the sort will become memory bound at somewhere between 8 to 16 cores, but I don't have the hardware to test this. The bottom up approach I mentioned would be a better way to test this. I wrote a Windows | Visual Studio program as a test https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/148025/59065.
